# Cross product of charlists or characters?

Tags: elixir

I wrote

```
iex(87)> cross=fn                                                           
...(87)> a, b when is_list(a) and is_list(b) -> for x <- a, y <- b, do: [x,y]
...(87)> a, b when not is_list(a) and is_list(b) -> for y<-b, do: [a,y]      
...(87)> a, b when is_list(a) and not is_list(b) -> for x<- a , do: [x, b]   
...(87)> end
```

which does the thing but gosh it's very ugly. I tried the much simpler

```
cross=fn(a,b) -> for x <- to_charlist(a), y <- to_charlist(b), do: [x,y] end
```

but this produced a lot of bogus results when sending in a single character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you essentially want is a way to wrap non-lists into a single element list and then your `for` will work as expected with char or charlists as either arguments. You can do this with `List.wrap/1`:

```
cross2 = fn as, bs ->
  for a <- List.wrap(as), b <- List.wrap(bs), do: [a, b]
end
```

Test:

```
cross = fn                                                           
  a, b when is_list(a) and is_list(b) -> for x <- a, y <- b, do: [x, y]
  a, b when not is_list(a) and is_list(b) -> for y <- b, do: [a, y]      
  a, b when is_list(a) and not is_list(b) -> for x <- a , do: [x, b]   
end

cross2 = fn as, bs ->
  for a <- List.wrap(as), b <- List.wrap(bs), do: [a, b]
end

IO.inspect cross.('abc', 'def')
IO.inspect cross2.('abc', 'def')
IO.inspect cross.(?a, 'def')
IO.inspect cross2.(?a, 'def')
IO.inspect cross.('abc', ?d)
IO.inspect cross2.('abc', ?d)
# Your implementation doesn't handle this case.
# IO.inspect cross.(?a, ?d)
IO.inspect cross2.(?a, ?d)
```

Output:

```
['ad', 'ae', 'af', 'bd', 'be', 'bf', 'cd', 'ce', 'cf']
['ad', 'ae', 'af', 'bd', 'be', 'bf', 'cd', 'ce', 'cf']
['ad', 'ae', 'af']
['ad', 'ae', 'af']
['ad', 'bd', 'cd']
['ad', 'bd', 'cd']
['ad']
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use [`Kernel.to_string/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#to_string/1), that effectively flattens joined lists, and `<<c <- string>>` generators:

```
cross3 = fn a, b ->                            
  [a, b] = Enum.map([a, b], &Kernel.to_string([&1]))
  for <<x::utf8 <- a>>, <<y::utf8 <- b>>, do: [x, y]            
end

IO.inspect cross3.('abc', 'def')
#⇒ ['ad', 'ae', 'af', 'bd', 'be', 'bf', 'cd', 'ce', 'cf']
IO.inspect cross3.(?a, 'def')
#⇒ ['ad', 'ae', 'af']
IO.inspect cross3.('abc', ?d)
#⇒ ['ad', 'bd', 'cd']
IO.inspect cross3.(?a, ?d)
#⇒ ['ad']
```

Comment: One thing: you'll want to do `x::utf8` and `y::utf8` to get the same behavior as charlists for non-ASCII input.